# Array of pointers to (arrays of pointers to objects)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My goal is to create an array where each cell holds a pointer to another array of pointers to objects (a data processor class I defined.) I have multiple arrays of the same type, declared as follows:

```
dataProcessor *dparr[num];
```

I dynamically allocate and store pointers to dataProcessor objects in these arrays. Each array has the same number of pointers.

I'd like to make a sort of container array to contain pointers to each of these, so that I can pass that as an argument to a function I wrote that will put each array of pointers to objects on its own thread for data processing.

So my attempt was to do something like this as a test:

```
dataProcessor** king_arr[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        dataProcessor *dparr[(UPPER_CHUNK_LIM-LOWER_CHUNK_LIM)+1];
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2; j++){
            string dir = ABS_PATH + to_string(j) + "/";
            dparr[j] = new dataProcessor(dir, filenames, j);

        }
        king_arr[i] = dparr;

    }
```

However, I run into an issue where each cell in king_arr points to an empty array of 16 null pointers? The program will correctly store the two elements from the inner for loop and then the rest is just garbage. Only the values of *[0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqxUr.png) are valid. Also, why is it "*[0]" and not just "[0]"? Picture below:

[image]

If this is not enough information, please let me know if I need to add anything else. The dataProcessor constructor doesn't do anything weird. It doesn't do anything with manual memory management. Pretty run of the mill class.

**TL;DR**

I feel like the problem is with me actually storing it via:

```
king_arr[i] = dparr;
```

If this is the mistake, can someone explain conceptually what I messed up and what the correct method is?

**Instead of down voting this and not helping, could you please tell me how I can improve my post? I'd be happy to do that.**

Comment: `dparr` is locally allocated, don't store its address to some more global structure. Prefer dynamic allocation...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès ok but why does king_arr have 16 entries per cell then?

Comment: May be `(UPPER_CHUNK_LIM-LOWER_CHUNK_LIM)+1` equals to 16...

Comment: If you are using C, then use `malloc` instead of `new`. If you are using C++, perhaps use the STL `vector` class, instead of an array.

Comment: Right, choose the appropriate tag C or C++

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès UPPER_CHUNK_LIM = 2, LOWER_CHUNK_LIM = 1, so the difference plus 1 is 2.

Comment: You need to allocate dynamically first, you face a serious problem, correct it first before asking why this wrong code produces wrong values.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Can you please post a correction showing what you mean? Having trouble visualizing where this is going wrong. (haven't dealt with issues like this before, so still learning.)

Comment: @jonnyd42 Can you post a [MCVE] in your question please, that reproduces the behavior.